# What is the match rule of Feature Dependencies?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

When I set the required features of a feature, I add "test.feature.A" and don't specify its version, why there is an Error icon on this feature? I don't see any error message.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UipCL.png)

test.feature.A :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feature id="test.feature.A" label="A" version="1.0.0.qualifier">

    <description url="http://www.example.com/description">
      [Enter Feature Description here.]
    </description>

    <copyright url="http://www.example.com/copyright">
      [Enter Copyright Description here.]
    </copyright>

    <license url="http://www.example.com/license">
      [Enter License Description here.]
    </license>

</feature>
```

test.feature.B

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feature id="test.feature.B" label="B" version="2.0.0.qualifier">

    <description url="http://www.example.com/description">
      [Enter Feature Description here.]
    </description>

    <copyright url="http://www.example.com/copyright">
      [Enter Copyright Description here.]
    </copyright>

    <license url="http://www.example.com/license">
      [Enter License Description here.]
    </license>

    <requires>
        <import feature="test.feature.A"/>
    </requires>

</feature>
```

Moreover, if I specify its version and don't specify its Match Rule, what is the actual match rule ?

```
<requires>
    <import feature="test.feature.A" version="1.0.0.qualifier"/>
</requires>
```

Comment: Please show a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and a non-cropped screenshot that also shows `test.feature.A` and `test.feature.B` as well as that there is nothing in the _Problems_ view.

Comment: @howlger hello, I add some infomation, these two features are very simple in order to test.